# Can I ask a question on binary compatibility?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a question on what binary compatibility means, and if there is any definition for that .

Will this question be on-topic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My view is no, such a question would not be on-topic here.

IMHO that is a general computer science question and too far from the core on-topic subjects for this site. It would be better suited to Computer Science.SE or Stack Overflow. In fact, I just checked and see that you have already [asked the question on Computer Science.SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142463/what-kind-of-binary-compatibility-is-present-for-2-processors-sharing-an-instruc).

So even though you have mentioned this topic in comments on an [answer to one of your recent questions on this site](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/576322), that doesn't make it on-topic as a question itself here.

Sorry if that is not the answer that you wanted.

Comment: It is not the same question as Computer Science.SE. I wanted to ask the definition of binary compatibility.

Comment: My answer remains the same. Thanks.